# Is there a way to kill reducer task in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

Running a few map reduce jobs and one job takes over the all the reducer capacity. Is there a way to kill one or two reducer tasks to free up the cluster?

I can go directly to the one of the task tracker server and kill the java process manually. But I am wondering if there is a more decent way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can kill the task-attempt by :

```
hadoop job -kill-task [task_attempt_id]
```

To get the task-attempt-id, you need to go one level deeper into the task(by clicking on task hyperlink on job tracker).

Answer (score 3):

First find the job ID:

```
hadoop job -list
```

Now, kill the job:

```
hadoop job -kill <job_ID_goes_here>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this kills the entire job.. I only want to kill one task, and let the remaining run. The goal is just to free up a slot for my other light-weight jobs to run.

Comment: Ok, then you can manually killed it as you indicated. However, this is a very poor use of your resources, since the other tasks won't release their slots until the one you killed is re-executed. Instead, take a look at the CapacityScheduler, and use queues with limits to ensure that one job cannot take the capacity of the whole cluster (even if it wants to).

Answer (score 0):

`hadoop job -kill-task [attempt-id]` wherein the attempt-id can be obtained from the UI.